# Bulk Changes Latex

Tags: texlive

Is there a way to apply bulk changes to multiple .tex files in one folder or project?

For example, add a watermark to all .tex files, or add an image in the top corner of all the files.

Comment: To the source or the compiled PDF? In the latter case they no longer `.tex` files but adding an image to the top corner of your `.tex` source doesn’t seem sensible.

Comment: tex files are just text files so any editor ought to be able to apply changes across a range of files.